# How to find th values of variables that maximize an objective in a system of differential equations using Python? (Batch Reactor Optimization)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, differential-equations, scipy-optimize

I have a system of first and second order differential equations for dilute acid hydrolysis in a batch reactor and I want to find the values of B0, HA and T that maximize the quantity (X+A) (with 15<B0<25, 0.03<HA<0.22, 373<T<453). I have solved the system for arbitrary values B0, HA and T but I don't know how to optimize their values. Is there a way to do this in python other than manually changing their values and comparing the results?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Biomass Weight Fractions
xc = 0.4068       # Cellulose
xh1 = 0.22136     # Xylans
xh2 = 0.03786     # Arabinans
xh3 = 0.0333      # Acetyls

# Kincetic Parameters
R = 8.314/1000 # kJ/(mol K)
k10 = 2.37 # Xylans and arabinans preexponential factors
n1 = 1.51  # Xylans and arabinans acid concentration exponent
E1 = 83.3 # Xylans and arabinans activation energy (kJ/mol)
k20 = 2.17 # Xylose preexponential factor
n2 = 0.29 # Xylose acid concentration exponent
E2 = 143.5 # Xylose activation energy (kJ/mol)
k1ac0 = 2.37 # Acetyls preexponential factor
n1ac = 0.604 # Acetyls acid concentration exponent
E1ac = 83.3 # Acetyls activation energy (kJ/mol)
k30 = 2.37 # Cellulose preexponential factor
n3 = 1.359 # Cellulose acid concentration exponent
E3 = 94.962 # Cellulose activation energy (kJ/mol)

# Maximum Concentrations
Bmax = 120 # Maximum Biomass Concentration (g/L)
Xylmax = xh1*Bmax  # Maximum Xylan Concentration (g/L)
Arabmax = xh2*Bmax # Maximum Arabinan Concentration (g/L)
Acetmax = xh3*Bmax # Maximum Acetyl Concentration (g/L)
Celmax = xc*Bmax   # Maximum Cellulose Concentration (g/L)

# Design Variables
B0 = 140 # Initial Biomass concentration (g/L) or 14% w/v
HA = 0.08 # Sulfuric acid concentration (mol/L)
T = 120+273 # Reactor Temperature (K)

# Initial Concentrations
Xyl0 = xh1*B0  # Initial Xylan concentration (g/L)
Arab0 = xh2*B0 # Initial Arabinan concentration (g/L)
Acet0 = xh3*B0 # Initial Acetyl concentration (g/L)
w0 = 0 # Initial condition for dAcetdt
Cel0 = xc*B0   # Initial Cellulose concentration (g/L)
X0 = 0   # Initial Xylose concentration (g/L)
A0 = 0   # Initial Arabinose concentration (g/L)
Ac0 = 0  # Initial Acetic Acid concentration (g/L)
u0 = 0   # Initial condition for dAcdt
G0 = 0   # Initial Glucose concentration (g/L)
F0 = 0   # Initial Furfural concentration (g/L)

# Kinetic Model
t = np.linspace(0, 240, 720) # Time (min)
def model(z, t):
    Xyl = z[0] # Xylan concentration (g/L)
    X = z[1] # Xylose concentration (g/L)
    Arab = z[2] # Arabinan concentration (g/L)
    A = z[3] # Arabinose concentration (g/L)
    Acet = z[4] # Acetyl concentration (g/L)
    w = z[5] # derivative of Acet
    Ac = z[6] # Acetic acid concentration (g/L)
    u = z[7] # derivative of acetic acid
    Cel = z[8] # Cellulose concentration (g/L)
    G = z[9] # Glucose concentration (g/L)
    F = z[10] # Furfural concentration (g/L)
    K1 = k10*(10**10)*(HA**n1)*np.exp(-E1/(R*T)) # min-1
    K2 = k20*(10**15)*(HA**n2)*np.exp(-E2/(R*T)) # min-1
    K1ac = k1ac0*(10**10)*(HA**n1ac)*((Xyl/Xyl0)**2)*np.exp(-E1ac/(R*T)) # min-1
    K3 = k30*(10**10)*(HA**n3)*np.exp(-E3/(R*T)) # min-1
    ef1 = 1/(1+((Xyl/Xylmax)**20)) # Xylan effective coefficient
    ef2 = 1 / (1 + ((Arab / Arabmax)**20)) # Arabinan effective coefficient
    ef3 = 1 / (1 + ((Acet/Acetmax)**20)) # Acetyl effective coefficient
    ef4 = 1 / (1 + ((Cel/Celmax)**20)) # Cellulose effective coefficient
    Xylef = 0.95*ef1*Xyl+(1-ef1)*Xylmax # Xylan effective concentration
    Arabef = 0.95*ef2*Arab+(1-ef2)*Arabmax # Arabinan effective coefficient
    Acetef = 0.95*ef3*Acet+(1-ef3)*Acetmax # Acetyl effective coefficient
    Celef = 0.95*ef4*Cel+(1-ef4)*Celmax # Cellulose effective coefficient
    dXyldt = -K1*Xylef
    dXdt = K1*Xylef-K2*X
    dArabdt = -K1*Arabef
    dAdt = K1*Arabef-K2*A
    dAcetdt = w
    dwdt = (-K1ac*Acetef-10*w)/4
    dAcdt = u
    dudt = (K1ac*Acetef-10*u)/4
    dCeldt = -K3*Celef
    dGdt = K3*Celef
    dFdt = K2*(X+A)
    return [dXyldt, dXdt, dArabdt, dAdt, dAcetdt, dwdt, dAcdt, dudt, dCeldt, dGdt, dFdt]

# System of differential equations solver
z0 = [Xyl0, X0, Arab0, A0, Acet0, w0, Ac0, u0, Cel0, G0, F0]
z = odeint(model, z0, t)
Xyl = z[:, 0]
X = z[:, 1]
Arab = z[:, 2]
A = z[:, 3]
Acet = z[:, 4]
w = z[:, 5]
Ac = z[:, 6]
u = z[:, 7]
Cel = z[:, 8]
G = z[:, 9]
F = z[:, 10]

# Effective functions
ef1 = 1/(1+((Xyl/Xylmax)**20)) # Xylan effective coefficient
ef2 = 1 / (1 + ((Arab / Arabmax)**20)) # Arabinan effective coefficient
ef3 = 1 / (1 + ((Acet/Acetmax)**20)) # Acetyl effective coefficient
ef4 = 1 / (1 + ((Cel/Celmax)**20)) # Cellulose effective coefficient
Xylef = 0.95*ef1*Xyl+(1-ef1)*Xylmax # Xylan effective concentration
Arabef = 0.95*ef2*Arab+(1-ef2)*Arabmax # Arabinan effective coefficient
Acetef = 0.95*ef3*Acet+(1-ef3)*Acetmax # Acetyl effective coefficient
Celef = 0.95*ef4*Cel+(1-ef4)*Celmax # Cellulose effective coefficient

# Yields
X_yield = (Xyl0-Xyl)/Xyl0 # Xylose yield
A_yield = (Arab0-Arab)/Arab0 # Arabinose yield
Ac_yield = (Acet0-Acet)/Acet0 # Acetic acid yield
G_yield = (Cel0-Cel)/Cel0 # Glucose yield

# Concentration plots
plt.style.use("seaborn")
small_size = 10
medium_size = 12
big_size = 14

plt.rc('font', size=small_size)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=big_size)    # Controls size of chart title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=big_size)    # fontsize of the x and y axis titles
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=medium_size)   # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=medium_size)   # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=small_size)    # legend fontsize

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(t, Xyl, label="Xylan Concentration")
ax1.plot(t, Xylef, label="Xylan Effective Concentration")
ax1.set_xlabel("t (min)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Concentration (g/L)")
ax1.legend()

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(t, Arab, label="Arabinan Concentration")
ax2.plot(t, Arabef, label="Arabinan Effective Concentration")
ax2.set_xlabel("t (min)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Concentration (g/L)")
ax2.legend()

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.plot(t, Acet, label="Acetyl Concentration")
ax3.plot(t, Acetef, label="Acetyl Effective Concentration")
ax3.set_xlabel("t (min)")
ax3.set_ylabel("Concentration (g/L)")
ax3.legend()

fig4, ax4 = plt.subplots()
ax4.plot(t, Cel, label="Cellulose Concentration")
ax4.plot(t, Celef, label="Cellulose Effective Concentration")
ax4.set_xlabel("t (min)")
ax4.set_ylabel("Concentration (g/L)")
ax4.legend()

fig5, ax5 = plt.subplots()
ax5.plot(t, X, label="Xylose Concentration")
ax5.plot(t, A, label="Arabinanose Concentration")
ax5.plot(t, G, label="Glucose Concentration")
ax5.plot(t, F, label="Furfural Concentration")
ax5.plot(t, Ac, label="Acetic Acid Concentration")
ax5.set_xlabel("t (min)")
ax5.set_ylabel("Concentration (g/L)")
ax5.legend()

fig6, ax6 = plt.subplots()
ax6.plot(t, X_yield, label="Xylose Yield")
ax6.plot(t, A_yield, label="Arabinose Yield")
ax6.plot(t, Ac_yield, label="Acetic Acid Yield")
ax6.plot(t, G_yield, label="Glucose Yield")
ax6.set_xlabel("t (min)")
ax6.set_ylabel("Yield (% wt)")
ax6.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Apply scipy.optimize.minimize to the function you describe (change the sign to switch from maximum to minimum). There are other procedures in that module that are more specialized in the method used.

Comment: I recommend you using `Pyomo` in the [DAE](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modeling_extensions/dae.html) module to find the optimal problem